# java script dialog box with 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms

to maintain consistency with the alert and prompt dialogs boxes in java script I am wondering if there is a dialog box which cab accept 2 inputs instead of one?

I have tried a couple of methods like :

creating a form

```
<form id="management_form">
Enter Option: <input type="text" id="optiontb" name="option">
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction(this.form)" value="submit"> </form>
```

and calling

```
document.management_form.submit(); in the java script method
```

this displays the form wherever the form code is in the htmlfile. and not when the form is called

and creating

a form using

```
var newdiv = document.createElement();
newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry  <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
document.appendChild('newdiv');
```

for this I see and error Uncaught error:NOT_FOUND_ERROR:DOM Exception8

Are there better ways to do this ?

Edit:
After performing some operations as suggested below by Girish :

the html code is as follows :

```
<title>
<style>
 I have include the code for the style
</style>
<script>
 function request()// renamed it here 
   { // this is exactly same the code in the sample web site
      }
```

how i am calling this java script method

```
 function myfunction(frm)
  {
var opt=frm.option.value;  
request();
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

}
this gets called from

```
 <form name="management_form">
  Enter Option: <input type="text" id="optiontb" name="option"> 
 <input type="button" onclick="myfunction(this.form)" value="submit"> </form>
```

anything that can be added here so that this gets displayed as a dialog and not like a html page ?

Comment: It is `document.body.appendChild('newdiv');`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this type of functionality, so you can check this URL

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

and it you liked this then please download its code and implement this into your code.....

Comment: thanks for this, but I am unfortunately seeing the div form where ever I have included in the html code, and not like a dialog box as it appears on your web page. I will include the error and findings in the question above

Comment: i realised that the code sample in the link above makes use of jquery ui plugin i would rather not make use of many plugin because I need the ui to be very very light weight, any thoughts on this ?